# Is it good practise to put assets in component directories itself?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, architecture

I researched best practises on react architecture, but never saw images or other assets being put in component directory, I am considering to do that, because it looks more maintable approach to me, but maybe I'm wrong, how is it actually, has anyone ever done that?

what do I mean, insead of having this:

```
└── src
    ├── assets
    └── components
        ├── my-component
        |   └── MyComponent.js
        |
        └── other-component
            └── OtherComponent.js
```

I am considering to having this

```
└── src
    └── components
        ├── my-component
        |   ├── assets
        |   └── MyComponent.js
        |
        └── other-component
            ├── assets
            └── OtherComponent.js
```

Comment: It is easier to serve static files from one folder. Also you usually use the same assets across mutliple components.

Comment: If there assets like styling or images that are specific to a single component or tightly coupled group of components, it's cleaner to put those assets along side those components. If there's assets that are shared between components, or that don't relate to components (like CSS reset of favicons) then they can go in a distinct assets folder. That's my opinion anyway